# regex to find hashtags in tweet not working correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying to build a function to find a `hashtags` in tweest. And surround them with an `HTML <a> tag`. so that I can link to them. Here is what I do.

```
NSError* error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?:\\s|\\A)[##]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:tweetText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [tweetText length])];
for ( NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches )
{
    NSString* matchText = [tweetText substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSString *matchText2 = [matchText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *search = [matchText2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#"
                                                            withString:@""];
    NSString *searchHTML= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href='https://twitter.com/search?q=%%23%@'>%@</a>",search,matchText];
    tweetText = [tweetText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:matchText
                                                    withString:searchHTML];
    NSLog(@"match: %@", tweetText);
}
```

Before I execute this function, the tweetText is looped through another function to find the URL. so the tweet can contain the following. `<a href='http://google.be' target='_blank'>http://google.be</a>`

Now sometimes it places another  tag around other links and not only around the hashtags.

Can somebody help me with this.

**TIP**

I am trying to transform the following JAVA code into OBJ-C

```
  String patternStr = "(?:\\s|\\A)[##]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)"
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr)
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tweetText)
     String result = "";

     // Search for Hashtags
     while (matcher.find()) {
     result = matcher.group();
     result = result.replace(" ", "");
     String search = result.replace("#", "");
     String searchHTML="<a href='http://search.twitter.com/search?q=" + search + "'>" + result + "</a>"
     tweetText = tweetText.replace(result,searchHTML);
     }
```

EDIT

```
Gers, we kijken er al naar uit! “@GersPardoel: We zitten in België straks naar Genk!!<a href='<a href<a href='https://twitter.com/search?q=%23='http'>='http</a>s://twitter.com/search?q=%23https:/'>https:/</a>/twitter.com/search?q=%23engaan'> #engaan</a>” #GOS12 #genk #fb
```

Comment: Pl provide an example of failing test case. I don't see a problem with your `...google.be...` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying your `tweetText` variable (`tweetText = ...`) as you're looping through matches. Imagine what happens the next time code enters the loop? The `substringWithRange` will not work properly since it was created on the original string. Try to rectify the problem and if you're unable to do it, check the solution here: http://pastebin.com/DyQqtRzA

EDIT: Adding solution here:

```
NSError* error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?:\\s|\\A)[##]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:tweetText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [tweetText length])];
NSString* processedString = [[tweetText copy] autorelease];
for ( NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches )
{
    NSString* matchText = [tweetText substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSString *matchText2 = [matchText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *search = [matchText2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#"
                                                            withString:@""];
    NSString *searchHTML= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href='https://twitter.com/search?q=%%23%@'>%@</a>",search,matchText];
    processedString = [processedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:matchText
                                                                 withString:searchHTML];
    NSLog(@"match: %@", processedString);
}
```